# If Else Decisions in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a small LINQ query to populate a dropdown control (WinForms Telerik app ) with rows of data showing two values (ITNBR and Description):

```
var query = from i in db.ItemMasts.AsNoTracking()
orderby i.ITNBR
select new { i.ID, cboText = i.ITNBR + " - " + i.Description };

//Now we can bind the results to the control
cbo.DataSource = query.ToList();
cbo.DisplayMember = "cboText";
cbo.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Which works fine. But I want the user to be able to switch the order of the "cboText" - as in sometimes it shows as ITNBR - Description and sometimes it shows as Description - ITNBR

Is there any way to do this without writing two separate LINQ queries?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes use ternary operator `select new{ i.cd, CboText = isuseflag? i.ITNBR + " - " + i.Description :  i.Description + " - " +i.ITNBR  }`

Comment: whats the condition for the if statement? A user setting or is it based from the query?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The condition would just be a Boolean variable passed into the routine (Boolean ITNBRFirst) - something like that. So if (ITNBRFirst == true) etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes use ternary operator. Suppose you use `isUserflag` to decide order if it's true one order and false then second order.

```
 var query = from i in db.ItemMasts.AsNoTracking()
 orderby i.ITNBR
 select new { i.ID, cboText = isUserflag ? i.ITNBR + " - " + i.Description : i.Description + " - " +i.ITNBR };
```

Comment: Thanks folks - that worked perfectly! Now I just need to 'evenly space' the items in the dropdown. I thought using CourierNew as the font would do it but unfortunately it doesn't....